# if else structure not working with for certain text, I'm using Google recapture may be?

Tags: php

`if else` conditions are workig for below.
However, it is not working for the bottom two strings.

```
if ($business_category =="Computer Consulting Services" ) { $seo = "IT Consulting"; }// working


if ($business_category =="Computer & IT - Training & Development" ) { $seo = "IT Courses"; }//not working
if ($business_category =="Computer & IT - Technical Support" ) { $seo = "IT Support"; }//not working
```

Error is: `unidentified variable seo`.

Comment: Tried replacing & with &amp; still didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting the values for $business_category? Are you getting them from a database, user input or other php functions?

Depending on the source, the "&" sign might be escaped. For example, it might be stored as "&". Check the value of $business_category using var_dump($business_category) to make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: not DB, I'm using input from drop-down list :) tried using &amp; and &#038; still no luck

Comment: What is the output from var_dump($business_category)?

Comment: Oh, let me check the input form for the drop-down list, good sugession

Comment: this is what they look like:

Comment: <option value="Computer & It - Technical Support">Computer & It - Technical Support</option>
          <option value="Computer & It - Training & Development">Computer & It - Training & Development</option>

Comment: I think it doesn't like & with dash (&-) in the string

Comment: That's all fine.you need to be certain how PHP sees the value. It might be escaped in ajax get / post. So check the variable $business_category in php file first using var_dump. Then decide if you need to change anything in php or html select option.

Comment: this is the value for var_dump: string(38) "Computer & IT - Training & Development"      using below code:$seo="Computer & IT - Training & Development";
  echo var_dump($seo);

Comment: If you assign the variable and checking it in PHP, you will get the same value. It will not tell you anything extra. What you need to check is how data is transmitted to php from browser when user selects the option (via form upload or ajax). I would expect the follwoing: 
$business_category = $_REQUEST["your_query_variable"];
var_dump($business_category ); //check how & is represented here.